# How can i find the order of the detected circle?

Tags: opencv

I have images with few circles in it each circle of different size.I have to find the radius   of each circle for calculation so i was using Hough circles and i was able to find the radius  of detected circle.Since i have many circles with different size how can i find which   radius is belongs to which circle?
For example i have 3 circle c1,c2,c3 and hough detection return me 3 radius r1,r2,r3 now how can i get which one belongs to which circle.

Comment: manually verifying the output of Houghcircle is not possible thats the reason am asking this. if i check manually it is easy to find beacause i can see the detected circle. continous imaging and detection is involved in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hough Circle in OpenCV

EG:

```
vector<Vec3f> circles;

HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, src_gray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );
```

The circles object has the center points stored in it.

```
x = circles[i][0];
y =circles[i][1];
radius = circles[i][2];
```

EG: This will draw the circles

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
{
   Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
   int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
   // circle center
   circle( src, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
   // circle outline
   circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
 }
```

Comment: hough circle works fine for me and return the radius thats not the problem. lets say it returns 3 radius how will i find which circle its belongs to.

Comment: I don't understand how this could be causing you a problem. Please post a code except with you returning the radius. The center point of the circle is normally encoded with it. You do realise that a center point and a radius is all it takes to describe distinct circles don't you?

Comment: my problem is that i need the radius for calculation and houghcircles return that thats fine. i have created a small artifact which contain few spheres which i have to detect. the value of the radius changes acording to the distance from the artifact. so sometime when the distance increase it happen that out of 4 only 3 sphere detect, since i have to do this automatically i cannot take the output of the image and verify manually. thats the reason am asking this

Comment: Can you colour code the spheres to make them distinct? Otherwise you will have to already have an idea of their arrangement (ie a 3D model) to calculate which one has been dropped.

Comment: My spheres are of similar color beacause it is easy to detect. later i will be calculating the 3d position of each that, so that i can use some algorithms to find the best fit. in order to do that i have to know which one is detected which one is not.

Comment: If you have no way of making them distinct/loading in a 3D model of their placement you will not be able to determine which ones are displayed. You will have to factor missing spheres into your best fit matching algorithm. There is nothing to be done at the image processing level. This is why 3D reconstruction using SURF and SIFT require many feature points to be stable. Your issue is no different.

Comment: that makes sense. But still i wish for a solution

Comment: I think you should repost the question as a best fit problem over at the dsp stack. They would have more experience with best fit algorithms. There is nothing that can be done on the OpenCV side beyond detecting the circles.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parameters of the circles detected, through using the function cvHoughCircles().

Comment: How will that function help?

Comment: @fuQiang which parameter of cvHoughCircles give me which radius belongs to which one, when i have few circles in the image and houghcircle detect few out of that?